# Increment counter within ng-repeat in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two nested ng-repeat and would like to access both the outer and inner indexes.

```
<div ng-repeat="column in columns" ng-init="columnIndex = $index">
     <div ng-repeat="row in column" ng-init="rowIndex = $index">
          <p ng-click="delete(column, row)">
              Delete
          </p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Now, this works fine as long as the **outers** model isn't updated.
Apparently, ng-init initializes the values only once so columnIndex and rowIndex  will not be update accordingly if I delete one element on the page.

Is there an other way to keep track of the outer and inner index so the correct values can be passed to the delete function?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18360841/increment-counter-in-item-generated-with-ng-repeat

Comment: @Ellery That other person wanted to modify the model on click. I don't, A specific value needs to be attributed to each delete function.

Comment: why do you need it in delete function? Easy to get indexing in controller with what you have and don't need $index

Comment: you need to use some uniqueIdentifier in your array itself, depening on $index i not good idea

Comment: @charlieftl Maybe I'm doing it wrong, but I need to know which value to delete from the model array.

Comment: @pankajparkar I understand what you mean, but then in my delete function I would have to parse the array once again to find the correct one to delete. That's why I was using a coordinates system to delete the correct one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a name for each ng-repeat index:

```
<div ng-repeat="(columnIndex, column) in columns">
    <div ng-repeat="(rowIndex, row) in column">
        <p ng-click="delete(column, row)">
            Delete
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively you can use `$index` for the inner index and `$parent.$index` for the outer index.

Comment: I feel dumb, I didn't even think of the keys.
But still, I didn't know about the $parent.$index, so thanks!